# Divergence of field in spherical coordinates does not match Cartesian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates, divergence-operator

I have a vector field

$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\frac{x \hat{x}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{y \hat{y}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} + \frac{z \hat{z}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

Solving this in Cartesian coordinates, I found that the divergence is 0. However, the process was tedious and error-prone. I'm sure there must be an easier way to solve this. I tried converting the vector field to spherical coordinates, because I recognized the $x \hat{x} + y \hat{y} + z \hat{z}$ as $\rho \hat{\rho}$, which gave me:

$$\vec{F}(\rho,\theta,\phi)=\frac{\rho \hat{\rho}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

And taking the divergence of this in spherical coordinates, I get $$\frac{3}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$
which is not the correct answer. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please transfer the whole function into the other coordinate system..

Comment: $\vec{F}(\rho, \theta, \phi) = \frac{}{r^2} \hat{\rho}$

Comment: Show your calculations.. otherwise we won't be able to find your mistake

Comment: @Buraian how does the vector field look in spherical coordinates? I know the divergence is 0 because I checked that with a calculator. I'm also sure that my transformation from cartesian to spherical coordinates is incorrect as I checked the correct divergence with a calculator. So can I not represent ̂+̂+̂ as ̂?

Comment: You have to distinction between the space and the coordinates. What you need to do is transfer the function which is dependent on reality from cartesian to spherical coordinates. Your unit vector transformation is correct but you gotta change the denominator as well if you want to make the derivative process easy.

Comment: You write the function is dependent on spherical variables but have x,y,z in denominator..

Comment: I am not sure how you got the three on the numerator.. did you use the divergence operator in cartesian here? It's not a good idea to mix the operators in different coordinate systems like that. Look up the voss-weyl formula if you want to know the generalized recipe for taking divergences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be careful about the singularity at the origin. Yes the divergence is zero at all points but the origin.

To convert to spherical coordinates, know that $\hat\rho=\frac{x \hat{x}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} + \frac{y \hat{y}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} + \frac{z \hat{z}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$

and $\rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

So, $\vec{F}(\rho,\theta,\phi)=\frac{1}{\rho^2} \hat{\rho}$

As we only have $\hat \rho$ component, divergence at points other than the origin in spherical coordinates is given by,

$ \displaystyle \nabla \cdot \vec F = \frac{1}{\rho^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial \rho} (\rho^2 F_{\rho}) = 0$.

Depending on the context of the problem and the domain, you will have to handle the origin differently. For example, this is a very well known vector field in Electrodymanics. In other words, if origin is part of your domain, do not trivially assume that divergence is zero. It is not zero at the origin for the given vector field.

Comment: how did you get from the second paragraph to the third paragraph, where you define the field to be $\frac{1}{\rho^2} \hat{\rho}$?

Comment: also, I thought $\rho$ was just $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$? I know the $\rho$ you used is different because it's a unit vector, but how did you find the value of $\hat{\rho}$? And why must I use $\hat{\rho}$ here instead of $\rho$?

Comment: In denominator you have, ${(x^2+y^2+z^2)}^{3/2}$ which is $ (x^2+y^2+z^2) \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: See 3rd row and 1st column in unit vector conversion section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: So after converting to unit vector in spherical coordinates, you are left with $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Comment: In fact what you wrote is the same $\vec{F}(\rho,\theta,\phi)=\frac{\rho \hat{\rho}}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$ but you need to write  $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2} = \rho^3$

Comment: Oh, I see. So if I have a general vector field, say $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = F_x \hat{x} + F_y \hat{y} + F_z \hat{z}$ and I wanted to convert it into spherical coordinates, what would be the general way to do it? Would I look into converting the cartesian basis vectors into spherical basis vectors first, and then making substitutions like $\rho = (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}$? Or would I use a matrix transformation as specified in the wiki page? Is there a general procedure for how this can be done? Thanks!

Comment: You have to expression the cartesian basis vectors in terms of the spherical basis.. this can be done through the jacobian. The component functions you have to change their variable intos i nto spherical

Comment: Yes as @Buraian mentioned. See row $1$ column $3$ in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to transform the denominator.
We have $x\hat x + y\hat y + z\hat z= \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{||(x,y,z)||}= ||(x,y,z)|| = \rho$, and $(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}= ||(x,y,z)||^3=\rho^3$.
So your function in spherical coordinates is
$$\vec F(\rho,\theta,\phi) = \frac{\rho}{\rho^3} = \rho^{-2}$$
Since this does not depend un $\theta,\phi$ the divergence is just
$$ \mathrm{div} F = 1/\rho^2 \frac{d}{d\rho}(\rho^2 F) = 1/\rho^2 \frac{d}{d\rho}1 = 0$$

Comment: what do the double bars mean? ||

Comment: Your first equations need to be corrected.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you.

Comment: @rjc810 $||\vec v||$ is the norm of the vector $v$, i.e. $\sqrt{\sum v_i^2}$